# Instantiate variable = new Object;

Tags: php, class, object

I'm starting doing php OO (I know javaOO) but I wish someone could help me instantiate a variable so that I can call its methods.

A couple of hours ago I read an article and I would do it. How you can pass object session from PHP to MySQL.

I put all class from GitHub end.

I'm using this tutorial: http://culttt.com/2013/02/04/how-to-save-php-sessions-to-a-database/

Full 2 class: https://github.com/plagodzinski/dbsession/tree/master/include

I'm trying instanciate with :

```
$ObjSession = new Session; // this line get a error and not work
```

What I'm wrong ?

**Updated 13/01/2016 16;47**

**This is my error:**

```
Warning Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object
```

**Class Session**:

```
class Session
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct() {

        // instantiate the new database object
        $this->db = new Database();

        // set handler to override session
        session_set_save_handler(
            array($this, "_open"),
            array($this, "_close"),
            array($this, "_read"),
            array($this, "_write"),
            array($this, "_destroy"),
            array($this, "_gc")
        );

        // start the session
        session_start();
    }

    // check if the database connection is up
    public function _open() {
        if ($this->db) {
            return true;
        } 

        return false;
    }

    // close the database connection
    public function _close() {
        if ($this->db->close()) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    // read session values
    public function _read($id) {
        $this->db->query('SELECT data FROM sessions WHERE id = :id');

        if ($this->db->execute(array($id))) {
            $row = $this->db->single();
            return $row->data;
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }

    // write session values
    public function _write($id, $data) {
        $access = time();
        $this->db->query('REPLACE INTO sessions VALUES (:id, :access, :data)');

        if ($this->db->execute(array($id, $access, $data))) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    // destroy session
    public function _destroy($id) {
        $this->db->query('DELETE FROM sessions WHERE id = :id');
        if ($this->db->execute(array($id))) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    // garbage collection
    public function _gc($max) {
        $old = time() - $max;

        $this->db->query('DELETE * FROM sessions WHERE access < :old');

        if ($this->db->execute(array($old))) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**Class Database**:

```
define("DB_HOST", "");
define("DB_NAME", "");
define("DB_USER", "");
define("DB_PASS", "");

class Database
{
    private $host = DB_HOST;
    private $user = DB_USER;
    private $pass = DB_PASS;
    private $dbname = DB_NAME;
    private $dbh;
    private $error;
    private $stmt;
    public function __construct() {
        // set DSN
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
        // set OPTIONS
        $options = array(
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
        // create a new PDO instance or catch any errors
        try {
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    // prepare statement
    public function query($query) {
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    }

    // bind values and execute statement
    public function execute(array $params = null) {
        $this->stmt->execute($params);
    }

    // fetch single row result
    public function single() {
        try {
            return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    // fetch all results
    public function resultset() {
        try {
            return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    // fetch output parameter from stored procedure
    public function outParam($paramName, $paramAsName) {
        $this->stmt->closeCursor();
        return $this->dbh->query('SELECT ' . $paramName . ' AS ' . $paramAsName)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }

    // get affected rows count
    public function rowCount() {
        return $this->stmt->rowCount();
    }

    // get the id of the last inserted row
    public function lastInsertId() {
        return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
    }

    // begin transaction
    public function beginTransaction() {
        return $this->dbh->beginTransaction();
    }

    // end transaction
    public function endTransaction() {
        return $this->dbh->commit();
    }

    // cancel transaction
    public function cancelTransaction() {
        return $this->dbh->rollBack();
    }

    // debug dump parameters
    public function debugDumpParams() {
        return $this->stmt->debugDumpParams();
    }

    // close connection
    public function close() {
        $this->dbh = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't really look into it, but didn't you just simply forgot the perenthesis? `new Classname()`. It might also be wise to turn on php errors so you can see what happened (`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and try to prevent the usage of error suspression `@`)

Comment: What error did you get? The opening php tag should be `<?php`, not `<?`.

Comment: Not sure why you've opted not to show the error... But twice in your code you seem to be successfully instantiating new objects.  (Do a "find" on this page for "new " to see them.)  So what exactly is the issue?

Comment: You cannot instantiate a variable. Variable can just contain a value, which can be for example an instance of the class (or more exactly reference to an instance of the class). An instance of the class is called object.

Comment: And look here, `> ? `, the closing tag in `Database` class is also wrong.

Comment: And as others wrote, you can't fix an error without the error message. If you're getting an error on the line with class instantiation, it's most probably because you're missing the parentheses. But it can be also, for example, Session class not found etc. This is just guessing.

Comment: Ohh!! sorry is <?php ?>, yes! When I try assign $ObjSession  = new Session; (as the tutorials say http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php-for-beginners--net-12762 ) I updated my post I get error

Comment: As @RajdeepPaul wrote. I just would recommend to not use the PHP closing tag at all (at least if you don't need to switch to HTML mode, which you shouldn't need) to prevent such errors. Also it's absolutely critical to enable the error reporting, it's not possible to develop with it disabled.

Comment: @Named But your error is just a warning and happened on a completely different line, that you suggested previously. Property `$this->dbh` simply doesn't contain an object. Why did you post a different and unrelated error? As I wrote before, use one question for just single question. You didn't solve previous error and you're just adding more and more issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay, I amused myself doing other things:

Solution :

> I get errors in the same file I do not know very well (best import)

```
include('database.class.php');
include('session.class.php');
```

> Instantiate

```
$session = new Session();
```

> Add query / execute (Database)

```
PDOException $e
```

> Important all arrays need a token(:) to recognize ":variable"
>   =>$variable

`$this->db->execute(array($id))` to `$this->db->execute(array(":id" =>$id))`

After all steps you can save session to mysql